# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '02-10-2021' to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to replace all instances of the "GETDATE" aspect of the code below to be the date "02-10-2021", however I'm receiving the following error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '02-10-2021' to data type int

Code:

```
SELECT * 
FROM PM_NOTIFICATION_ORG_VIEW_FW  
WHERE (NEXTSERVWEEKS_FW = DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, -23, GETDATE())) 
  AND vehicle_id_fw NOT IN (SELECT vehicle_id_fw 
                            FROM booking_headers_fw 
                            WHERE reason_code_fw LIKE 'PM%' 
                              AND schedule_date_fw >= GETDATE() - 7)
  AND vehicle_id_fw NOT IN (SELECT vehicle_id_fw 
                            FROM job_details_fw 
                            WHERE reason_code_fw LIKE 'PM%' 
                              AND job_detail_date_fw >= GETDATE() - 7))
```

I can't recall how to get this to work, please help! Thank you.

Comment: This is why I hate syntax like `getdate()-7`. Dates aren't numbers, they are dates. If you replace `GETDATE()` with `'02-10-2021'` you get `'02-10-2021' - 7` and that literally makes no sense. Fix your code, and use proper date logic to affect your dates; such as `DATEADD` and `DATEDIFF`.

Comment: Also, when using literal strings for dates use an unambiguous format. In SQL server that's `yyyyMMdd` or `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.nnnnnnn`.

Comment: Thank you Larnu, that was a huge help. I was able to achieve the results that I wanted.

Comment: Instead of just the literal value, convert the literal value to a datetime (or equivalent) datatype. Instead of replacing with "02-10-2021", replace it with CONVERT(DATETIME, '02-10-2021').

Answer (score 0):

You need a `datetime` value for your version of using `-` on dates.  I would recommend instead:

```
SELECT *
FROM PM_NOTIFICATION_ORG_VIEW_FW n CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES (CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())) v(the_date)
WHERE NEXTSERVWEEKS_FW = DATEADD(day, -23, v.the_date) AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM booking_headers_fw bh
                  WHERE bh.reason_code_fw LIKE 'PM%' AND
                        bh.vehicle_id_fw = n.vehicle_id_fw 
                        bh.schedule_date_fw >= DATEADD(DAY, -7, v.the_date)
                 ) AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM job_details_fw jd
                  WHERE jd.reason_code_fw LIKE 'PM%' AND
                        jd.vehicle_id_fw = n.vehicle_id_fw 
                        jd.schedule_date_fw >= DATEADD(DAY, -7, v.the_date)
                 );
```